# Solving equation using eval(),equation entered by user on html page

Tags: javascript, html

I am want to evaluate the equation entered by the user using eval().To read
the input I am using querySelector but its not working.

```
<html> 
<body>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <input type="text" name="equation" id="equation" placeholder="enter equation eg: 2+4">
            <button type="button" id="button" onclick="evaluate()">Result</button><br>
            <div style="width:150px; height:50px; color:red; background-color:white;" id="result">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
 function evaluate(){
var input = document.querySelector('#equation');
var inputVal = input.innerHTML;
var btnVal = this.innerHTML;
var r1 = eval(btnVal);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=r1;

}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `evaluate()` is a `built-in javascript` function available with `document`.

You need to `change` your `function name` because when you click on button it is calling `javscript evaluate` function and not your `function`.

```
function Evaluate() {
var input = document.getElementById('equation');
var inputVal = input.value;
var r1 = eval(inputVal);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = r1;
}

<button type="button" id="button" onclick="Evaluate()">Result</button><br>
```

Comment: how can I do it using "query selector" ??

Comment: Why do you need query selector ?

Comment: @mairaj-ahmed how come if I try to call evaluate in my browser console I get an error saying it is not defined?

Comment: @otajor Are you calling evaluate with a capital E? (`Evaluate();`)

Comment: just wanted to try.

Comment: @PriyankaMaurya If you want to use `document.querySelector` just replace `document.getElementById('equation')` with `document.querySelector('#equation')` and `document.getElementById("result")` with `document.querySelector('#result')`

Comment: @PriyankaMaurya you can use query selector like `document.querySelector('#equation')` but to get the content of textbox use `.value` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: @Tobsta nope, just `evaluate()` or `evaluate` to try and see the function. Neither work, both not defined...

Comment: @otajor The function is defined as `Evaluate` in this example, so it needs to be called with a capital E.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: It is not safe to `eval()` to arbitrary (and not yet validated) user's input.

For your solution to work, you can try though

Replace

```
var inputVal = input.innerHTML;
var btnVal = this.innerHTML;
```

with

```
var btnVal = input.value; //input's value you need rather than its innerHTML
```

Comment: @PriyankaMaurya do you get any errors in browser console?

Comment: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': 2 arguments required, but only 0 present.  

error on button.

Comment: @PriyankaMaurya on which line?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
<html><body><div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <input type="text" name="equation" id="equation" placeholder="enter equation eg: 2+4">
        <button type="button" id="button" onclick="evaluar()">Result</button><br>
        <div style="width:150px; height:50px; color:red; background-color:white;" id="result">
    </div>
</div></body><script>function evaluar(){
var input = document.getElementById("equation");
var inputVal = input.value;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=eval(inputVal);}</script></html>
```